# How to use substring to extract certain text

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code that extracts certain text from an HTML source:

```
string url = txtURL.Text;
string pageCode = WorkerClass.getSourceCode(url);
int startIndex = pageCode.IndexOf("</B>");
pageCode = pageCode.Substring(startIndex, pageCode.Length - startIndex);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("websitesource.txt");
sw.Write(pageCode);
sw.Close();
```

The above code writes the following to the text file:

```
</B> WILLIAMS AJAYA L                     <BR>                                                                      
<B>Address : </B> NEW YORK            NY                                          <BR>                                        
<B>Profession : </B> ATHLETIC TRAINER                          <BR>                                                           
<B>License No: </B> 001475 <BR>                                                                                            
<B>Date of Licensure : </B> 01/12/07      <BR>                                                                                
<B>Additional Qualification : </B>     &nbsp; Not applicable in this profession                       <BR>                    
<B> <A href="http://www.op.nysed.gov/help.htm#status"> Status :</A></B> REGISTERED                                        <BR>
<B>Registered through last day of : </B> 08/15      <BR>
<HR><div class ="note">                                                                                                       
* Use of this online verification service signifies that you have read and agree to the                                       
<A href="http://www.op.nysed.gov/usage.htm">terms and conditions of use</A>.
```

How can I use the code within a forloop to store the text (any spaces around it trimmed) in a string array?

So the string array should have it like this:

```
string[] ar = {
"WILLIAMS AJAYA L",
"NEW YORK          NY",
"ATHLETIC TRAINER",
"001475",
"01/12/07",
"Not applicable in this profession",
"REGISTERED",
"08/15"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it slightly differently than Selman22 using a string split command. I also remove `&nbsp;` and replace with space. Also, this will work regardless of where line breaks are at (since HTML doesn't require any specific formatting).

```
var split = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME)
                .Replace("<BR>", "").Replace("&nbsp;", " ")
                .Split(new[] {"<B>", "</B>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Where((x, i) => i%2 == 0)
                .Select(y => y.Trim()).ToList();

split.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
Console.ReadKey();
```

The important part of this is to make sure your data is always in this format - as HTML can change frequently and simple changes to the DOM will completely throw off your parsing.

Best of luck!

Comment: Well the FILE has more text below to what I posted. I would like JUST those text listed above... Any way to do that?

Comment: Your going to have to write parsing specific to the data you have. You can see what I wrote working here: https://ideone.com/WrSFAD

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines =  File.ReadLines("websitesource.txt")
                .Select(line =>
                    line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf("</B>") + 4)
                        .Replace("<BR>", "")
                        .Trim())
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: In my existing code, it saves it to my DEBUG folder in my project. Shouldn't it also do the same thing?

Comment: I had the spelling wrong so that's fixed. But it didnt write anything to the file :/. It is inside `bin/Debug` or should it be under the `bin` only?

Comment: this code is not for writing, (yes it should be inside bin/Debug)

Comment: ahhhhhhh.... I was just about to say :)... So how do I access the Array if I may ask :)?

Comment: The text of the indexes that are stored in the array

Comment: OOOOHHHHHHHHHHHHHH I first have to write the file that is doing in my existing code and THEN run your code... Gotcha :)